# How to extract delivery failure in SwiftMailer?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Docs for SwiftMailer say:

> It’s possible to get a list of addresses that were rejected by the Transport by using a by-reference parameter to send(). As Swift Mailer attempts to send the message to each address given to it, if a recipient is rejected it will be added to the array.
>
> ```
> // Pass a variable name to the send() method
> if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
> {
>   echo "Failures:";
>   print_r($failures);
> }
> ```

However, I do not see a way to determinate what was the reason for this failure. E.g. `send` returns 0, `$failures` is filled with e-mail address, but I would like to know why sending has failed/rejected.

How can I do this? Is it not possible? A quick look inside sources indicate that SwiftMailer `catch`es exceptions to fill `$failedRecipients` and it seems that exception's message is not saved anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Run_Script So, it is not possible. Can you make this an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to do this. Unfortunately it is only possible to see the list of email addresses that failed rather than the reasons for these addresses failing.

From the discussion on GitHub (https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/891):

> Exceptions are swallowed silently in `\Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::_doMailTransaction()`